# Upgrade AdWords API from version v201609 to v201705

Tags: api, upgrade, google-ads-api

I am using Adwords API version of v201609 and want to upgrade the version to v201705. I have downloaded the API integration folder from [https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib][1]

In my version v201609, I used below code and in the new version v201705 there is no folder structure like this.

```
require_once getcwd() . '/protected/adv20169/examples/AdWords/v201609/init.php';
require_once getcwd() . '/protected/adv20169/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/v201609/ReportUtils.php';
```

If anyone can help me with the step by step instruction to upgrade the Adwords API from version version v201609 to v201705, that would be helpful. Can't find such an instruction while google it.

Answer (score 0):

The library seems to have been changed.

Here is new ads PHP client library upgrade guide.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/cfc0c930a4b4063042d0553e5a31b57b619982a6/UPGRADING.md